# Howto download Chromium v77 in Dockerfile with Alpine?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chromium

I am currently using the node:12-alpine Docker image and I am trying to install Chromium version 77, but I am unable to figure out how as I can not find a package for it.

I am fine with changing to a different docker image if that would allow me to install Chromium version 77.

**Question:**

How can I download and install Chromium version 77 in a docker image?

Comment: you can download up to V76 from offical repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3.x version of alpine which has Chromium v77

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache chromium
```

PS: I also added `chromium-driver` and `libcanberra-gtk3` module for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps curl \
    && curl -fSL https://chrome.com/chrome.tar.gz -o chrome.tar.gz
```

Just download it, it should be fine.
download chrome:

[chrome download](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?path=Linux_x64/)

Comment: the url in the command returns a 404 and I have absolutely no idea what to download from the link you provided

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux%2F382086%2Fchrome-linux.zip?generation=1458337367735000&alt=media   download at this page: 
 http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux/382086/

Comment: you can refer to this page： https://askubuntu.com/questions/60133/where-can-i-find-chromium-binary-tarballs